# I want to split string in text words and get first character on each string

Tags: vb.net

I have a text box with text like " Spring street" and i want split into two words and get first character of each word like

"SS" 
i am beginner so please help me

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. After that has been done, please edit your question accordingly

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far, and how / where it isn't working.

Comment: I think this was also ask in this thread. TY
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829822/split-character-in-word)

Comment: `Dim output() As Char = input.Split().SelectMany(Function(c) c.Take(1)).ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

```
' Split string based on spaces.
  Dim words As String() = s.Split(New Char() {" "c})

  Dim answer As string
  answer = answer(0).Substring(0, 1) + answer(1).Substring(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow.

Below is a piece of code that returns the requested

```
    ' Define the string that needs to be splitted
    Dim texttosplit As String = "Spring street"

    ' Split the string into words
    Dim words As String() = texttosplit.Split(" ")

    ' Loop each word to compile a result string
    Dim resultstring As String = Nothing
    For Each word As String In words
        resultstring = resultstring & word.First
    Next
```