# Split character in word

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to separate this word, as an example the String is ASP_01, so I want to separate it into two like store ASP in one variable and the 01 in another variable, is it possible for me to do this in asp.net visual basic,

I am newbie in this,

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Yes it's possible but it's not for us to explain the basics here.  You need to do some research first and only post here when you have made your best attempt and failed.  Splitting strings is something that you can find information on in a matter of seconds with a web search.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Split Function. [Link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet)

```
dim str As String = 'ASP_01'
dim newWord As String = str.Split(new Char {"_"c})

dim 1stWord As String = newWord[0] //result is "ASP"
dim 2ndWord as String = newWord[1] //result is "01"
```